# Path of ASP.NET Core appsettings.json in Docker Container

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I plan to mount a created appsettings.{env}.json file as a volume from the host into the container. Does anyone know the path of appsettings.json in Docker Container? Or how can I get the path using docker command?

I'm deploying ASP.NET Core Web App with a Windows Server Core Docker image to a Windows Docker Container.

I want to use it for the docker command below.

```
docker run -v <path-to-appsettings.json-on-host>:<path-to-appsettings.json-inside-container> <container-name>
```

Comment: It’s extremely dependent on the specific image being run.  There is no universal answer to this.

Comment: @DavidMaze, I've added some details on my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this is the command i need to use. In Windows Container using Windows Server Core image the path of appsettings.json is "C:\app\appsettings.json.

docker exec -it {container id} cmd